# Count selected rows after auto filter

Tags: vba, excel

When my data are raw and unfiltered I can select them and `Selection.Rows.Count` returns the valid number.

After the AutoFilter it returns a number as if I selected the rows that were not visible, even though `Selection.Copy` does not copy other than selected rows.

How do I get the valid count of selected rows?

I tried `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count`.

**EDIT**

I use filter in another macro and then select by hand rows I want to add to another sheet.

I did two buttons, one to filter my table and the second to move selected rows to another sheet.

```
Sub ajout_commande()
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prepa Commandes")
Dim a As Range, b As Range
Set a = Selection
i = 0
s = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
For Each b In a.Rows
    i = i + 1
    DataSheet.Cells(6, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    DataSheet.Range("A1:Z1").Copy DataSheet.Cells(6, 1).EntireRow
Next

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
Let copyrange1 = "E1" & ":" & "I" & i
Let copyrange2 = "BK1" & ":" & "BM" & i
Set r1 = a.Range(copyrange1)
Set r2 = a.Range(copyrange2)
Set r3 = Union(r1, r2)

r3.Copy
DataSheet.Cells(6, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
MsgBox s & " and " & i

End Sub
```

Here my table is filtered and I want to add selected rows to another sheet but the Selection.Rows.Count returns more rows than I selected because it counts the non visible rows, even though `Selection.copy` works.
[image]

For this example Selection.Rows.Count = 28 because of non visible rows between rows 10 and 20, 21 and 25 etc.

Is there a function to get the number I want (on this image 16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are using it. This works just fine for me

```
'~~> Remove any filters
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

'~~> Specifying the complete address is the key part
With Range("A1:C6") '<~~ Filter, offset(to exclude headers)
    .AutoFilter Field:=YOURFIELDNUMBER, Criteria1:=YOURCRITERIA
    Debug.Print .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
End With

'~~> Remove any filters
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

**Test**

```
Sub Sample()
    '~~> Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    With Range("A1:C6") '<~~ Filter, offset(to exclude headers)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Sid"
        MsgBox .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    End With

    '~~> Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yeah I wasn't clear on how I use it. the thing is that I have a button to filter my table and then I want to select some rows and click on one button to copy those rows to another sheet with some specific column only and modifying them a bit I don't want to filter and count the selected rows in the same vba macro. I will add more description to my post

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following would work **if** your selection was contiguous:

```
Selection.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

However, from your screenshot I can see that your selections may be non-contiguous ranges (aka multiple areas selected), so you can use this function I created as a starting point:

```
Function countVisibleSelectedRows()
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For Each Area In Selection.Areas
        count = count + Area.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count
    Next
    countVisibleSelectedRows = count
End Function
```

When you have multiple ranges selected, Excel calls each of those ranges an "area". In this function, we loop over each "area" in the Selection.Areas collection.

Comment: When I print this number it print 16331 for 1 selected row on excel. I think this represent the number of cells in my row when I select 2 rows it print 32662.

Comment: Oh, I see now what you're trying to do. I've edited my comment to make this work how you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late post to this question, but maybe this will help someone in the future.  I find the following code snippet works well to count the number of visible rows in a range after being filtered.

```
Sub CountVisibleRows()
'only count the visible rows in the range

Dim lRow As Long, vis_lr As Long, DstWs As Worksheet

Set DstWs = ActiveSheet

lRow = DstWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'vis_lr = DstWs.Range("B2:B" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count   'doesn't seem to work with non-contiguous rows

With DstWs
vis_lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("B2:B" & lRow))
End With

Debug.Print vis_lr

End Sub
```